# how do I scan a document on my hp deskjet 2430 using ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, hplip

I have already downloaded hplip and I got it to work once before, but I don't remember where to go to select graphics, scan, photo.  I can't find the menu to access.  where is it?

Comment: did you try the launcher (super "windows" button)?

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. This will most probably be the Windows key on keyboard.

This will open up Dash.

Here type Scan, and will be able to see a program called `Simple Scan`.